# RegEx for any number of white spaces or digits, with a total length of 13

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I am working on a RegEx in which I want any number of occurrences of white spaces and any number of occurrences of digits in the total length of 13. Something like

```
'           12'
```

or

```
'       115678'
```

Current Regex:

```
(^\s*\d[0-9]{1,12})$
```

How to get this variable occurrences using blocks

Comment: My data is right aligned filled with blanks in the left. No just reg ex

Comment: By using anything in Reg ex

Comment: So you've got, a bunch of spaces followed by a bunch of digits and you want the _whole thing_ (spaces and digits) to be up to 13 characters long, correct?

Comment: Use `^[ 0-9]{1,13}$`

Comment: Why regex? PHP has functions that can do this without regex

Answer (score 0):

You can allow upto 13 spaces and/or numbers with a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
^[\t \d]{1,13}$
```

If `white spaces` also includes new lines use the `\s` meta character in place of the space and `\t`.

```
^[\s\d]{1,13}$
```

If this is PHP you can use `\h` for horizontal whitespaces, Javascript doesn't support that.

```
^[\h\d]{1,13}$
```

A demo (of version 2): https://regex101.com/r/gZ9rA8/1

Non regex PHP version:

```
$string = '       115678';
if(strlen($string) <=13 && is_numeric($string)) {
    echo 'It\'s GOOD!';
}
```

https://eval.in/639391

Non regex javascript:

```
var string = '       111578';
if(string.length <= 13 && !isNaN(string.trim())) {
     alert('good');
} else {
    alert('bad')
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/h9mx0tmn/

Answer (score 0):

Since there are two conditions to be met:-

1. any occurrences of white spaces followed by any occurrences of digits
2. total length of 13

Use positive look ahead regex like this:-

```
/(?=^\s*\d*$)(^.{13}$)/
```

Visit here for more about positive look ahead regex:-

[Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This matches any string in format of `\s*\d+.*` up to 13 characters.

Comment: Edited the quantifier of the first condition.

Comment: You didn't get me. It also matches ` 6ABCDEFGHIJK`

Comment: @revo How if I move the start stop anchors into both conditions? Thanks for your guide.

Comment: @CapitalC Your regex will work ok, just it seems more efficient to check the length first.

Comment: Noted and thanks. I'm glad that I can try help and learn at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

You could do with one huge ugly and inefficient regular expression:

```
^\s{0}\d{13}|\s{1}\d{12}|\s{2}\d{11}|\s{3}\d{10}|\s{4}\d{9}|\s{5}\d{8}|\s{6}\d{7}|\s{7}\d{6}|\s{8}\d{5}|\s{9}\d{4}|\s{10}\d{3}|\s{11}\d{2}|\s{12}\d{1}$
```

I would **recommend against doing it this way** though. Instead, you should do something like that: check the string against the regular expression `^\s{0,13}\d{0,13}$` and then verify that its length is 13 in a separate step.

Comment: Or simply `^(?=.{13}$)\s*\d*$`

Comment: "I would recommend against doing it this way " - so would I. Especially, when there are a couple of simpler regular expressions covering the same.

Comment: @revo Good one. +1

Comment: @revo Your answer is the best. Thanks.